# Remove whitespace before enumerate

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I am using a list like this:

```
\section{My section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item My first item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

The problem is that `enumerate` produces a vertical whitespace just before the first item.

So if I use

```
\section{My section}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item My first item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

instead of just

```
\section{My section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item My first item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

the first item, "My first item", will have exact same location.

So the list environment seems to reserve a spot for text above it. I have tried using:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{partopsep=0cm, topsep=0cm}
```

but it doesn't change anything.

I guess I could use `\vspace{-some value}` just before my lists, but I need a more generic code, so I have to set the option globally.

## Edit

This code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\raggedright}{}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{2.5cm}{2.5ex}{0cm}

\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0cm, leftmargin=0cm, label={}}

\begin{document}

\section{Experience}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Software Developer
\item Project Manager
\end{enumerate}

\section{Education}
\begin{enumerate}
\item M.Sc.
\item B.Sc.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

As seen next to "Education", the problem is that the list 'reserves' some space for a paragraph just above it.

Comment: Try `\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt]` -- please note that `\section` has also a vertical skip!

Comment: `\setenumerate` is deprecated by the way (according to the manual) -- since the spacing below `enumerate` is ruled by `topsep` also changing `topsep` will also modify the `below skip` as well!

Comment: Still no difference :(

Comment: For me the vertical space is the same with or without "Some text" before the enumerate environment. Please provide a full MWE.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: You shoudn't do it like this. The enumeration only starts with "Some text" in the first line because of some confusion with your title-formatting. One correct way to do this would be to put all in a table.

Comment: Are you sure that it's because of some confusion with my title formatting? If I omit the list environment and just use `\section{Some section name} Normal paragraph text`, it looks just as I want it to. I just want to accomplish the exact same with a list environment being the first element after the section heading

Comment: Maybe you are right. If I insert a `\titlerule` with `\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\raggedright}{}{0pt}{}[\titlerule]`, it doesn't seem right

Comment: I'm not sure why there should be no vertical space between *Some text* and *Software Developer* in the first example.

Comment: See, if the solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286603/space-issue-in-resume/286861#286861 can help you. Used is old document class, however it solve your problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use a table for the job. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}%height of table rows
\onehalfspacing%linespacing

\begin{tabular}{l p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm}}
Experience & Software Developer\newline Project Manager\\[5mm]
Education & M.Sc.\newline B.Sc.\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but I really want to use sections if ever possible.

Comment: Why does it need to be a section?

Comment: So that I get a 'table of contents' in my PDF reader