# Space Issue in Resume

Tags: tables, sectioning, margins, resume, cv

I have the address, portfolio website fields to the side of my name in the resume. Although I used the flushleft command for the table with contact information etc, they do not seem to appear beyond the margin allocated for the sections in the resume. I am showing a MWE below highlighting the relevant aspects.

The screenshot of the output highlighting this issue is available for quick reference.[image]

```
\documentclass[resmargin,line]{res}
    \usepackage{enumitem}


    \def \address{Auckland\\Portfolio : https://github.com/XYTE}
    \def \author{\textbf{{XTZ}}}
    \def \email{pr1@gmail.com}
    \def \phnum{222-914-3572}

    \usepackage{setspace}                                    % Allows for custom margins, etc.
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{fullpage}                                    % Use the full page
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}                            % Font definition and input type
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                 % Font output type 
    \usepackage{mmap}                                        % Allows glyphs (e.g. ff) to copy properly (ASCII)
    \usepackage{textcomp}                                    % Supports many symbols such as copyright
    \usepackage{color}                                       % Allow for colored text, etc.
    \usepackage[]{hyperref}                                  % Allow hyperlinks (internal and external)
    \hypersetup{                                             % Custom hyperlink settings
        pdffitwindow=false,                                  % Window fit to page when opened
        pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00},                   % Fits the zoom of the page to 100%
        pdfnewwindow=true,                                   % Links in new window
        colorlinks=true,                                     % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,                                     % Color of internal links (black is necessary for printing quality)
        citecolor=black,                                     % Color of links to bibliography
        urlcolor=black,                                      % Color of external links
        pdfauthor = {XYZW},
        pdfkeywords = {},
        pdftitle = {XYZW: Resume},
        pdfsubject = {Resume},
        pdfpagemode = UseNone}

    \reversemarginpar    
    \oddsidemargin -0.4in
    \evensidemargin -0.4in
    \textwidth=6.3in
    \itemsep=0in
    \parsep=0in
    % if using pdflatex:
    \setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
    \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}

        \addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.1in}
        \addtolength{\textheight}{0.6in} 



    \usepackage{datetime}                                    % Custom date format for date field
    \newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}   % Defining month year date format

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}                                    % Used for custom page headers
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
    \rhead{\footnotesize \thepage} %header at the right
    \headsep = 0.5cm
    % FIRST PAGE ONLY (redefine the plain pagestyle)
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
    \headsep = 0.0cm
    \rhead{}
    }
    \usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
                marginparwidth=5mm,       % Length of section titles
                marginparsep=0.1mm,       % Space between titles and text
                margin=20mm,              % margins
                %includemp,
          noheadfoot,
          top=0.8in,left=0.5in,right=1.4in,bottom=0in,
          pdftex
                ]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{plain} % to use first page footer
    \begin{tabular} {
      p{\textwidth/3-\marginparwidth+2mm}
      p{\textwidth/3-\marginparwidth+2mm}
      p{\textwidth/3-\marginparwidth+2mm}}
      \begin{flushleft}
        \address
      \end{flushleft}
      &
      \begin{center}
      \normalsize{\author}
      \end{center}
      &
      \begin{flushright}
        {\phnum}
          {\email}   
      \end{flushright}
    \end{tabular}
    \section{\sc Education}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.12cm, itemsep=2pt]
    \item[] \textbf{University of Auckland}\hfill {\textbf{May 2017}} \\
     Master of Science, Computer Science \hfill {\textbf{GPA : 3.81/4.0}}
     \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I take it you're using the res.cls from here? http://ctan.org/pkg/res

Comment: @JamesNZ, yes. Sorry I had not mentioned it earlier

Comment: `res`  is very old and shouldn't be used any more. There are better alternatives.

Comment: Apart from the old class `res.cls`. Don't use `\sc`. Use `\textsc{Education}` or `\scshape Education` in general....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Does that really matter for a poorly updated 2.099 style?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Is it actually 2.099 already? I thought it's LaTeX 1.01 ;-) -- I wrote `Apart from ...`

Comment: Since you are not using  `res` in any way, i suggest to use `article` and `\section*` (note the star/asterisk)

Comment: @Johannes_B, I am using the res cls file for other parts of the resume not included in this MWE.  The issue could not be resolved. I am still unsure how the tabular command should be modified.

Comment: Not directly relevant: don't use `flushleft`, `center` and `flushright` in table cells. Instead this rather redefine column type. `p{...}`  always align cell content to the left border. For star try width `l`, `c` and `r`. Where you like to have table?

Comment: @Zarko, I have put up a screenshot for your reference. The table essentially is the entire information before the section Education has begun. Please refer to the MWE source for more details.

Comment: @envy_intelligence, I play a little with your MWE and on the end I gave up: (1) minor problems, easy to solve: (i) you have some packages loaded twice (ii) page set up is defined at list twice and also inconsistent (ii) table is wrong designed; (2) major problem, I can't solve: used package - (i) I can not find package description ... (ii) doesn't drive a line as you show on image in question, (ii) only partially  push section into margins. To figured this out, you need to read `res` manual.

Comment: @Zarko, Ohk, the lines were shown only to help visualization. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @envy_intelligence, see what I try to figured so far out from your MWE. In my attempt I delete all packages, for which I estimate as unnecessary for solving base problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** After searching for similar question on SE, I found number of them, from which I learned:

- package `res` is not compatible with `geometry`
- content of resume should be enclosed by `\begin{resume}` and `\end{resume}`
- parameter `margin` push sections in margin
- with `\renewcommand\sectionfont{...}` you can globally define font prperties for section

Considering aforementioned, with some tweaks, I managed to obtain:

[image]

**New codoe:**

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
    \def \address{Auckland\newline
                  Portfolio : https://github.com/XYTE}
    \def \author{\textbf{{XTZ}}}
    \def \email{pr1@gmail.com}
    \def \phnum{222-914-3572}

    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}   % Font definition and input type
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Font output type     
    \usepackage[]{hyperref}         % Allow hyperlinks (internal and external)
    \usepackage{datetime}           % Custom date format for date field
    \newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}   

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \rhead{\footnotesize \thepage} %header at the right
    \headsep = 0.5cm
    % FIRST PAGE ONLY (redefine the plain pagestyle)
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \headsep = 0.0cm
        \rhead{}
                            }
% new package                
    \usepackage{calc}                
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\renewcommand\sectionfont{\large\scshape}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{plain} % to use first page footer

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5in}{}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth+1.5in}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\address    & \author   &   \phnum\quad\email   \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}

    \section{Education}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.2in,topsep=-2pt,itemsep=2pt]
    \item[] \textbf{University of Auckland}\hfill \textbf{May 2017} \\
     Master of Science, Computer Science \hfill   \textbf{GPA : 3.81/4.0}
\end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

As you see, I added three package: `calc`, changepage`and`tabularx`.  With their help I manage to made consistent code for table and it position on page.

Comment: @envy_intelligence, I modify ma answer. Now it is more in "spirit" of `res` package, i.e. dirty tricks for section is eliminated.